# Angular 11 POST Method URL Query String

Tags: angular, http-post, query-string

This is my first time working with HTTP methods in any regard. I'm wanting to make a POST request to pass these four variables and values to my API.

```
date: number;
temperatureC: number;
temperatureF: number;
summary: string;
```

I know I could simply write out the query string like so `https://localhost:30233/WeatherForecast?date=13&temperatureC=4&temperatureF=23&summary=nice` in the POST method and that would work. But I understand that is not very efficient nor modular. Is there a better way of passing the query string using the POST method?

So far this is what I have. Which contains a POST method with no information being passed.

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-WeatherData',
  templateUrl: './AddWeatherData.component.html',

})


export class PostDataComponent {
  baseUrl: string;
  date: number;
  temperatureC: number;
  temperatureF: number;
  summary: string;
  
  

  constructor(public http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    this.baseUrl = "https://localhost:30233/WeatherForecast";
  }

  CreateData(postData) {

    let endPoints = ""
    this.http.post(this.baseUrl + endPoints, postData).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);

    });

  }
}
```

**POST METHOD FROM MY CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpPost]
        public String Post(Int32 Date, Int32 TemperatureC, Int32 TemperatureF, String Summary)
        {
            {
                Posted = (Date, TemperatureC, TemperatureF, Summary);
                return Posted.ToString();
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE:**
I think my controller is the problem now? After changing my code to fit the POST method I am now receiving this error.

```
{error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: "(0, 0, 0, )"
```

How would I go about solving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken there is an method in @angular/common/http called HttpParams that helps with building params object. Then when ready you can pass them as noted by Sanjay.

```
const params = new HttpParams()
  .set('page', PageNo)
  .set('sort', SortOn);

return this.http.post(this.baseURL + endpoints, {params})
```

Comment: I have attempted to implement this before as that is how other examples have been solved. However, I have been unsuccessful so far. Could you perhaps provide a bit more detail as to how to properly implement HttpParams?

Comment: I was using it a while ago so I rechecked the method right now but this seems like proper solution, look here (I don't have API service that I can run the query on but if you go to the network tab and find your query, then move to `form data` section you can see the `tempF=44&tempC=21` there) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m4eokm?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I can see the Form Data now with my variables but it seems as though I have another issue. When going to the response section, the tuple I created when making my POST method to hold these 4 variables remains (0, 0, 0, ) -- 3 empty integers and a blank string.   I'm receiving a 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0'

Answer (score 1):

```
params = {
date: number;
temperatureC: number;
temperatureF: number;
summary: string;
}

this.http.post(this.baseUrl , { params}).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);

});
```